# Can you identify this display?

Tags: digital-logic, clock, display

I found a large box of these digital desk clocks that look like WYSE terminals. [image: WYSE Technologies desk clock]

I'd like to repurpose the displays in them but I've never seen a connection like the one they have nor do I know what kind of display this is. Can anyone help determine what these are?

[image: the circuit board and back of display]

The back of the display is made of what looks like rubber and it rests across the contacts at the bottom of the circuit board.

[image: front of display]

Comment: Looks line a plain old LCD to me...

Comment: You might want to Google the term "zebra strip"

Comment: And there is a naked, and probably very common, clock chip die buried under that glob of epoxy on the PCB.

Comment: @plasmahh thanks, I believe it is a zebra connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That rubber strip does make electrical contact between the glass of the LCD display, and the thirteen fingers on the printed circuit board.
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Zebra_connector.jpg

If you look very carefully at the glass side of the strip, it is coated with (transparent) indium-tin-oxide, which is conductive, and connected to each segment of the display.

Since a clock has four digits, the seven-segment display needs to switch *at least* 22 segments on and off. With only 13 contacts to the controlling clock chip, those segments must be arranged as a matrix. There are many row/column combinations to test...good luck finding the right one. Perhaps it is seven-by-four...seven segments common to each digit, and four digits, requiring eleven fingers.

Comment: Thanks, for the input. This will be helpful. I was trying to figure out how to go about determining the pin out.

Comment: Order a simple LCD with the same number of pins and get it to work first.